# Java: Expand JFrame to the width of a JTable

Tags: java, jtable, jframe

So I'm playing with JTables now, and I see TONS of answers about how to resize a JTable to fit a JFrame. Well, I'm trying to do the opposite.

I've spent the day playing around and studying a wide range of different ways to adjust the way a table displays. I've got it pretty much perfect (although my use of multiple methods to get there might be a bit sloppy, but hey, I'm learning). The only issue is my Frame, it's a tiny bit too small for the table. The last few characters of text in my last column (only the records with long names in them) get cut off.

So, right now I have two ways that I'm considering approaching this, and I'm having trouble figuring out both. 1) expand the size of the frame, but set the table to have a fixed size and exist only in the center of the frame (with empty space on both sides). 2) set the size of the frame based on the size of the table.

Having trouble figuring out how to do either of these. Pasting my code below.

The only parts that won't be there are 1) TableColumnAdjuster, a class with mechanisms to adjust TableColumns found on WordPress. If you're not familiar with it, here's a link: https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/

2) MyTableModel, a customized version of AbstractTableModel that I made. If it's necessary to add it, I will.

```
public class AccountManager{

    private static ArrayList<Account> accountArray = new ArrayList<Account>();
    private JFrame mainWindow;
    private JTable accountListTable;
    private JScrollPane tableScrollPane;
    private JPanel mainMenuPanel;
    private JPanel cardSwitchPanel;
    private MyTableModel tableModel;
    private Font titleFont = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20);
    private Font tableHeaderFont = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 16);
    private Font cellFont = new Font("Sans-Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14);
    private DecimalFormat moneyFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###,###.00");
    private JButton mmAddButton, mmEditButton, mmSumButton;

    public AccountManager(){
        DefaultTableCellRenderer centerAlign;
        DefaultTableCellRenderer rightAlign;
        TableColumnAdjuster columnAdjuster;
        Dimension d;
        int tableHeight;
        JLabel mmTitleLabel, mmTextLabel;
        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
        JLabel programTitleLabel;


        /*
         * TABLE PANEL
         * displays a table of all saved accounts
         */
        tableModel = new MyTableModel();
        accountListTable = new JTable(tableModel);
        tableScrollPane = new JScrollPane(accountListTable);

        //Methods to modify properties of accountListTable object
        accountListTable.setFocusable(false);
        accountListTable.setShowGrid(false);
        accountListTable.setFont(cellFont);
        accountListTable.setRowHeight(20);
        accountListTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

        //Determine the height of the table viewport
        d = accountListTable.getPreferredSize();
        tableHeight = accountListTable.getRowHeight() * 5;
        accountListTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(d.width, tableHeight));
        accountListTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        //Methods to modify the properties of the TableHeader of accountListTable
        accountListTable.getTableHeader().setResizingAllowed(false);
        accountListTable.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        accountListTable.getTableHeader().setFont(tableHeaderFont);

        //Use DefaultTableCellRenderer to center-align the name column
        centerAlign = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
        centerAlign.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        accountListTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(centerAlign);

        //Use DefaultTableCellRenderer to right-align the amount column
        rightAlign = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
        rightAlign.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        accountListTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(rightAlign);

        //Adjust columns to fit data (uses TableColumnAdjuster class from Word Press post)
        columnAdjuster = new TableColumnAdjuster(accountListTable);
        columnAdjuster.adjustColumns();

        /*
         * MAIN MENU PANEL
         * displays the Main Menu of the program
         */
        mainMenuPanel = new JPanel();
        mainMenuPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        mmTitleLabel = new JLabel("<html><u>MAIN MENU</u></html>", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        mmTitleLabel.setFont(titleFont);
        mmTextLabel = new JLabel("Choose from the following options.", SwingConstants.CENTER);

        mmAddButton = new JButton("Add Account");
        mmEditButton = new JButton("Edit Account");
        mmSumButton = new JButton("Sum Accounts");

        //FIRST ROW
        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        gc.gridwidth = 3;
        gc.insets = new Insets(10, 0, 10, 0);
        mainMenuPanel.add(mmTitleLabel, gc);

        //SECOND ROW
        gc.gridy = 1;
        gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 10, 0);
        mainMenuPanel.add(mmTextLabel, gc);

        //THIRD ROW
        //Add Button
        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 2;
        gc.gridwidth = 1;
        gc.insets = new Insets(0, 10, 10, 10);
        mainMenuPanel.add(mmAddButton, gc);
        //Edit Button
        gc.gridx = 1;
        mainMenuPanel.add(mmEditButton, gc);
        //Sum Button
        gc.gridx = 2;
        mainMenuPanel.add(mmSumButton, gc);

        /*
         * CARD SWITCH PANEL
         * master panel attached to mainWindow
         * all other panels added to it
         */
        cardSwitchPanel = new JPanel();
        cardSwitchPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //cardSwitchPanel.add(tableScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        cardSwitchPanel.add(mainMenuPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        /*
         * MAIN WINDOW OF THE PROGRAM
         */
        mainWindow = new JFrame("Account Manager");
        mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainWindow.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        programTitleLabel = new JLabel("ACCOUNT MANAGER", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        programTitleLabel.setFont(titleFont);

        mainWindow.add(programTitleLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainWindow.add(tableScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainWindow.add(cardSwitchPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        mainWindow.setVisible(true);
        mainWindow.pack();
    }
}
```

Comment: frame.pack() might solve your problem

Comment: Is there anything wrong with using `JFrame#pack`?